# I can't seem to get mods working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to install mods for Minecraft, and nothing seems to work. I am using Forge 1.7.2.  When I install a mod and start the game, Minecraft works, but not the mods, and I don't know why.  I know I am doing everything correctly but none of the mods are doing anything.

When I try to download any other mod, they dont work either; they do the same as the first, or the game crashes when I press play.

I have been trying for a while to get mods working, and I can just tell that I'm very close. I also know I'm putting the mods in the right folder.

Comment: What version Forge/Minecraft are you using? What mods did you try to install? Please provide more information.

Comment: i am using version 1.7.2 of forgeand i am trying to install the backpack mod

Comment: are you trying to install the 1.7.2 version of the backback  mod? what version of minecraft are you using?

Comment: This question is a mess, you start it by saying your forge wont work, then you say when you startup the game you only get 3 default mods, then you say the game crashes when you install a mod... your flat out contradicting yourself. We cannot read your mind, and your questions are a car wreck. please calm down and take the time to write out your request in a manner that is easier to understand so we can help you.

Comment: well sorry then

Comment: ok so my question is how do i install minecraft mods using version 1.7.2 of forge because when i install them they dont show up

Comment: no matter what mod i am using it doesnt work

Comment: either the mod just doesnt work and it doesnt show up or the game crashes NO MATTER WHICH MOD

Comment: sry if i seem angry im just new to minecraft and i have been working on getting mods for 12 days

Comment: im just so angry its not simple for me

Comment: Where are you putting the mods? And what instructions are you following to install mods?

Comment: first i am opening my roaming folder and selecting .minecraft then i open the "mods" folder and then drag my mods into that folder

Comment: Is the mod a ZIP file?  Or what type of file is it?

Comment: it is a rar file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 5):

Versioning is **extremely** important when working with Minecraft mods.  You absolutely must have the version of the mod that will work with the version of Minecraft you are running.  Currently there are very few mods that support v1.7.2.  Most people will run an older version of Minecraft that supports the mods they want.

As an example, the [Backpack mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1492661-15x-16x-backpacks-v-12629/) is currently only working with Minecraft v1.6.2+ (that is, only the v1.6 subversions) and not any of the v1.7 subversions.

In order to use the mod, you will need to download and install the [v1.6.4 version of Forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?action=files) and the v1.6.2 version of the Backpack mod.